# Vue 3 SSR with SFC but without high level solutions

Tags: vuejs3, server-side-rendering, vue-sfc

I have pretty small vue 3 app. It's just a login form with very old fashioned lifecycle: it submits the login and password in a synchronous manner. May be i shouldn't use any frontend framework at all, but rather make do with jquery and some server side template engine as in the past. That's the thoughts that keep disturbing me, but i still see benefits in using vue. The idea of SSR in vue 3 is pretty [clear](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html#basic-tutorial), but how to convert my App.vue component (in SFC format) into a single js object like in the example?

I found a lot of very complex high level solutions like nuxt and vite-plugin-ssr, but I think they are too complex for such a small task.

About the app component itself. It has styles in separate scss files which are used as CSS modules, it has some styles in the component itself and it uses a part from bootstrap. Also it has no routing and other stuff related to large applications.

index.js:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import '@styles/bootstrap/index.scss'
import '@styles/index.scss'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

App.vue:

```
<script setup>
  // App.vue
  import { ref, watchEffect } from 'vue'
  import modal from '@styles/modules/modal.module.scss'
  import spacing from '@styles/modules/spacing.module.scss'
  import card from '@styles/modules/card.module.scss'

  // Some code
  // ...
  </script>

  <template>
    <!-- Some HTML -->
  </template>

  <style lang="scss">
    // Some style
  </style>
```

Comment: Please show your `App.vue` component. You can convert it in a very simple Vue App without SFC and run it without using any JS builder .

Comment: Completed the description with details about App.vue

Comment: It's not really clear, what do you want to have in the backend server side. The whole SSR solution depends on this.

Comment: I have rest api plus oauth2.0 authorization server on fastify. Most of the time its answers are json, but oauth2.0 is supposed to have UI for a login form. Thank you for the proposed solution. It's almost what i need, but the thing is i have another project with some set of styles which i want to reuse. These styles made in form of css modules. If i use vue 3 + vite i have css modules support out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer for the question "How to SSR the app that is not [as simple as a single javascript object](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html#rendering-an-app)" is to build it and import all the functions you need on the backend from the entry point of the bundle. I export `render` and `createApp` (that calls `createSSRApp` inside) in `entry-server.js` and import them on the backend from my `dist` folder. This is about working without `viteDevServer`. With `viteDevServer` things get more complicated (i didn't manage to get `vite`'s express middleware to work with `fastify` by now). Detailed step-by-step instructions that helped me a lot can be found [here](https://blog.codeminer42.com/making-a-full-stack-app-with-vue-vite-and-express-that-supports-hot-reload/).

Answer (score -1):

For a very simple Vue.js app you don't need a lot.

You could put it all on one HTML page rendered in backend. See the playground.

For `Sass` you will need a preprocessor.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Global CSS Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
    <!-- Current Page CSS-->
    <style>
        #app { line-height: 1.75; }
        [v-cloak] { display: none; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Vue App Template -->
    <div id="app" v-cloak>
        Counter: {{counter}}
        <button @click="plusOne">+1</button>
    </div>
    <!-- Vue.js -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
    <!-- Vue App Scripts -->
    <script>
        const { createApp, ref } = Vue
        const App = {
            setup(props, context) {
                //  <-- hier everything from <script setup> except imports
                //
                const counter = ref(0)
                const plusOne = () => counter.value++;
                return { counter, plusOne }
            }
        }
        createApp(App).mount('#app')
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```